# Snapd error while searching

Tags: server, snap

I'm a new snapd user and I've some trouble trying to use it.

I'm on a fresh ubuntu server 18.04 install.

I try few thing and most of the time I've this error, did someone already had the same issue ?

```
root@kanban:/#snap find test
error: Get
   https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/search?confinement=strict%2Cclassic&fields=anon_download_url%2Carchitecture%2Cchannel%2Cdownload_sha3_384%2Csummary%2Cdescription%2Cdeltas%2Cbinary_filesize%2Cdownload_url%2Cepoch%2Cicon_url%2Clast_updated%2Cpackage_name%2Cprices%2Cpublisher%2Cratings_average%2Crevision%2Cscreenshot_urls%2Csnap_id%2Clicense%2Cbase%2Csupport_url%2Ccontact%2Ctitle%2Ccontent%2Cversion%2Corigin%2Cdeveloper_id%2Cprivate%2Cconfinement%2Cchannel_maps_list%2Ccommon_ids&q=test:
   Forbidden
```